# Formidable using "end" event with file upload

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am using Formidable with Express in nodeJS in an attempt to have a simple single file upload scheme. I have confirmed that a file is actually sent over from the client-side, but where it seems to run into troubles is on the server-side.

#### index.js

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        const form = formidale();
        form.on('file', (filename, file) => {
            fs.rename(file.path, `./data/nodes.csv`, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`There was an error in downloading a CSV file: ${err}`);
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("CSV file has been uploaded correctly.");
                }
            });
        });
        form.on('error', err => {
            console.log(`There was an error in downloading a CSV file: ${err}`);
            return null;
        });
        form.on('end', () => {
            console.log(fs.readFileSync('./data/nodes.csv')); // test to see if file exists
            const nodes = assignMetrics();
            console.log(nodes);
            return nodes;
        });
        form.parse(req);
    });
}
```

The main trouble I seem to find is that the `form.on('end', ...)` event does not seem to wait till the file has finished uploading to fire. I have confirmed this by trying to read the file in the event, but by that point it doesn't exist? The documentation though appears to suggest it is only meant to fire "after all files have been flushed [from the APIs pipe it infers]".

There appears to be no other events available that might wait till the file has been uploaded to be called? I also don't want to start throwing in layers of promises and such unless it is the only option, as each new layer of promises I find is a chance for unintended effects to happen.

Comment: Try again with version 3.x, then use form.parse callback to know when it ends. Open an issue on github if it still does not work.